# How do Centos cloud images map to iso images

Tags: centos, cloud, openstack, qcow2, openstack-glance

Is it possible to figure out which cloud image maps to which iso release for Centos.

I would like a Centos 7.3 minimal image, but when I browse the Centos cloud image site I cannot see any references to minor releases .

http://cloud.centos.org/centos/7/images/image-index

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The four numbers at the end (e.g. `CentOS-7-GenericCloud-1705`) state the release date (May '17 in this case).

See this table for the relations between date and version number: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS#CentOS_releases

For 7.3, you want `1611`.

Comment: Do you know if they do an equivalent of a minimal install versions of the images ? and what the different extensions are .qcow2  .qcow2.xz  .qcow2c ?

Comment: I only see `qcow2.xz` extensions. `xz` is a [compression format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xz) and `qcow2` is a type of [disk image format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qcow).

Comment: OK thanks . Can anyone tell me if the cloud images in https://cloud.centos.org/centos/7/images/ are minimal builds ? or how I can tell without spinning them up ?  I'm looking for a minimal install image .